# Can I run 2 Mono asynchronous Reactor Core?

Tags: java, mono, flux, project-reactor

in java:

```
    Mono<response> response = mon.just()
    Mono<object> object = mono.just()
    return response.block()
```

Response and object are not dependent on each other.
Is there a way to run the 2 monos at the same time in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

There is more then one way. One easy solution is to use the `subscribeOn` operator:

```
Mono<response> response = Mono.just(...).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
Mono<object> object = Mono.just(...).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

Whenever someone subscribes to your Monos, it will happen in another thread. In this case the thread is taken from an existing pool. `Schedulers` offers a variety of methods that allow you to use existing threads or create new ones (see [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html)).

If you are interested in reactive streams and multithreading, I recently wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@abetteroliver/reactive-streams-and-multithreading-efd63b67de9a)  about it.

Comment: I did some tests running in parallel with `Mono.zip(...).block()` some webclient endpoints calls on a _Spring Boot_ application (version `2.4.1`), with and without `subscribeOn(Schedulers`: the parallel execution time compared to sequential was almost halved, adding `subscribeOn(Schedulers` made no difference. This might be because _Spring Boot_ automatically configures _Reactor Netty_ as the default server, which in turn uses elastic scheduler threads by default.

Answer (score 1):

If those 2 `Mono`s aren't related to each other in any way and you want to run them in parallel then I would recommend you to think about your design.

---

If you would like to run them in parallel and use thier result when both results are avialable:

```
Mono<Integer> source1 = Mono.just(1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
Mono<String> source2 = Mono.just("aaaa").subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());

Mono.zip(source1, source2, (integer, string) -> string.concat(integer.toString()))
        .subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Output:

```
"aaaa1"
```

---

If the result type is the same (but not requeired), then you could do:

```
Mono<Integer> source1 = Mono.just(1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
Mono<Integer> source2 = Mono.just(2).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());

Flux.merge(source1, source2)
        .map(number -> number * 10)
        .subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Notice that you can't expect which element will be available first so we use `Flux` to represent 2 results while in the first example, we used `Mono` to represent one result which consist of 2 results.

Output:

```
10
20
or
20
10
```

---

[More information about `Scheduler` class, available Schedulers in reactor lib and subscribeOn operation.](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#schedulers)

Answer (score 0):

```
Mono<response> response = mon.just();
Mono<object> object = mono.just();
return response.doOnSuccess(object.subscribe());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).