# Running cassandra queries in parallel using Java Reactor

Tags: parallel-processing, cassandra, spring-webflux, reactor, spring-data-cassandra

i have got an issue when trying to run multiple cassandra queries in parallel (Spring 5, Spring-Data, Cassandra 4, datastax driver 4.9.0).

This sample code is OK

```
Mono<String> mono1 = Mono.just("1").log().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
Mono<String> mono2 = Mono.just("2").log().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
Mono.zip(Arrays.asList(mono2, mono1), result -> result).block();
```

Logs show that each mono is exectuted in its threads (boundedElastic-X)

```
18:46:12.866 [boundedElastic-1] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
18:46:12.866 [boundedElastic-2] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
18:46:12.869 [boundedElastic-1] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | request(unbounded)
18:46:12.869 [boundedElastic-2] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | request(unbounded)
18:46:12.869 [boundedElastic-1] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onNext(2)
18:46:12.869 [boundedElastic-2] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onNext(1)
18:46:12.869 [boundedElastic-1] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onComplete()
18:46:12.869 [boundedElastic-2] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onComplete()
```

But when i replace my sample Mono by a cassandra query that insert a record using ReactiveCassandraRepository for ex

```
Mono<Content> mono1 = cassandraOperations.insert(entity1).log().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
Mono<Content> mono2 = cassandraOperations.insert(entity2).log().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
Mono.zip(Arrays.asList(mono1, mono2), result -> result).block();
```

I get these logs:

```
2021-03-21 18:49:14.769  INFO 5664 --- [oundedElastic-1] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1 : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxMapFuseable.MapFuseableSubscriber)
2021-03-21 18:49:14.769  INFO 5664 --- [oundedElastic-2] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2 : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxMapFuseable.MapFuseableSubscriber)
2021-03-21 18:49:14.771  INFO 5664 --- [oundedElastic-2] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2 : | request(unbounded)
2021-03-21 18:49:14.771  INFO 5664 --- [oundedElastic-1] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1 : | request(unbounded)
2021-03-21 18:49:14.781  INFO 5664 --- [        s0-io-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2 : | onNext(com.acme.content.entity.Content@36cdb2c5)
2021-03-21 18:49:14.781  INFO 5664 --- [        s0-io-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2 : | onComplete()
2021-03-21 18:49:14.784  INFO 5664 --- [        s0-io-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1 : | onNext(com.acme.content.entity.Content@50d5f4a4)
2021-03-21 18:49:14.784  INFO 5664 --- [        s0-io-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1 : | onComplete()
```

OnSubscribe() & request() method are done inside a dedicated thread (oundedElastic-X) as expected but i am suprised to see that OnNext() & onComplete() operations are done inside the same one (so-io-3).

I must have missed something, can someone explain the differences that happens in both samples ?

Thanks !

Comment: you dont need multiple `onSubscribe` as the reactor documentation states `Only the earliest subscribeOn call in the chain is actually taken into account. ` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_the_subscribeon_method

Comment: I just tried using a single onSubscribe() instruction but then monos are run in the same thread named "boundedElastic-1", not what i expect. I need each one to be run its own thread.

Comment: I dont see the reason as to they ”need” to run on their each thread. It will probably not go faster. But if you absolutley ”need” it you should look into using ”publishOn”. But you should read up on the threading model of reactor, everything will be executed on a single thread in the end anyway.

Comment: you mean that having non-blocking code should be enought for performance and that parallelizing could not be worth (assuming that database accesses are fast) ? 
I have found this interesting link that explain the differences when testing  with Mono.just(XXX) and a database driver reactive implementation.https://github.com/reactor/reactive-streams-commons/issues/21: 5) When subscribeOn and observeOn/publishOn act sometimes the same. 
Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: The link you posted only affects only static builder functions like `just` are you running `just` in your production database code? The link also still only uses 1 scheduler, not 2 like you are doing. As said before, having two wont change anything, only one will be used.

Comment: The link does not explain any of your code all it atates is that if you run a subscribeOn or a publishOn after a specific static operator, they might express the same behaviour. Why did you linke that when it has nothing to do with your case?

Comment: I dont't use Mono.just() in my project, only in the test code i reported in my message above. That explains why onNext() and onComplete() are done in a "boundedElastic-X" thread while it was not the case in the other one that uses Cassandra repository. 
In fact, my question was why some operations are done in distinct threads int he first sample code and not in the second that uses Cassandra and this link explains that when using Mono.just(), subscribeOn and publishOn will have the same behavior.

Comment: The github link uses only one Scheduler but the purpose is not parallelism. it does not combine or zip multiple Mono/Flux. The author just want to show the specific behavior tof Mono.just()
i got the sample code to zip multiple mono and have them run in parallel from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571182/can-i-run-2-mono-asynchronous-reactor-core

Comment: Could you explain when you say "having two [threads] wont change anything, only one will be used".  If 2 Monos are used to do some jobs, let's say it takes 1s for each job. Running Mono in distinct threads should take 1s, not 2s ? But ok, i agree i need to understand better what is really done when using reactive programming patterns.

Comment: i have not stated having two threads, i have stated having two `schedulers` wont change. in the reactor documentation you can read up on what different schedulers do, and how they work. When someone subscribes to your flow, reactor will go into what is called the assembly phase, it will call all operators in reverse order upstream until it finds a producer *just, or in your case the database) as it calls up it will assemble the flow, that will then get called downstream. If during this phase it will find a subscribeOn operator it will use that scheduler defined.

Comment: if you have two schedulers defined, it wont use 2 schedulers it will only use the earliest one, the other will get ignored. The scheduler you have chosen is `boundedElastic creates new worker pools as needed and reuses idle ones. Worker pools that stay idle for too long (the default is 60s) are also disposed. Unlike its elastic() predecessor, it has a cap on the number of backing threads it can create (default is number of CPU cores x 10). Up to 100 000 tasks submitted after the cap has been reached are enqueued and will be re-scheduled when a thread becomes available.`

Comment: `schedulers` dont actually do work, per sey, they `schedule work to be done on the event loop` the event loop is actually the one doing the work. If you are running webflux in an mvc app reactor will create one event loop which is a single loop that will do the work on a single core. If you are running a pure webflux application the server will start up as many event loops as there are cores on your machine.

Comment: a processing core usually has 2 threads, and then it can spawn 1000s of virtual threads to do `async` work, meaning it can deal with miltuple things as one, compared to `parallel` where you have two separate threads working on two different things usually on two different cores. You are dealing with `i/o` work which is most likely not cpu intensive work, you dont have to do heavy computational work on cpus, you need to schedule work on the event loop to fire off requests. It has more to do with orchestration, than raw cpu processing power.

Comment: `boundedElastic` in combo with `subscribeOn` means that when you call `block` the framework will pick one thread from the scheduler and stick with that to schedule all your work on the eventloop. If you insist on having 2 diffferent threads, you should as stated before switch to `publishOn` in the chain where you want the chain to pick a random thread from the schedulers thread pool and use that to execute that database query. I highly suggest you read up on threading and schedulers in the official documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers

Comment: as everything i have written here comes from the official documentation.

Comment: ok, thank you for your explanations & time, i'll check reactor documentation